# How do I use OneSignal with Android Studio to allow notifications to link directly into post content?

Tags: android, onesignal

I am using OneSignal notification implemented in my app and everything works well.

I want when user tap on the notification to go directly to the post *without* going into the main web view. I searched about it and found something called **additional data** but I don't know how to implement additional data inside the code using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Additional data is passed to the the `notificationOpened` method from the `NotificationOpenedHandler` interface.

Follow the OneSignal [4. Add Optional NotificationOpenedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-studio-sdk-installation#4-add-optional-notificationopenedhandler) guide to set it up and read your key out of the `additionalData` variable.

Example you can set `targetUrl` to `https://google.com` on the Additional Data section on the dashboard or the `data` field on the [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call. Then check for this key in `additionalData` and call `loadUrl` on your web view with the value.
Example.

```
public class YourActivityClass extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

      OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
        .init();
   }
   private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler {
      public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
         if (additionalData != null && additionalData.has("targetUrl"))
            webview.loadUrl(additionalData.optString("targetUrl"));
         }
    }
}
```

*Note: The code above will only work if your `WebView` is on your launcher `Activity`. If it isn't you will need to setup OneSignal init in your `Application` class instead and call `startActivity`.*

Comment: I applied everything but same problem i cannot access specific urlfromnotofication

Comment: @Ali I just updated my answer with more detail and some example code.

Comment: I have implemented the code that you have sent now if the app is opened and i send a notification with target url it open automatically but when i minimize the app and i send a notification with target url and i tap on the notification nothing happened and the app don't open

Comment: also take into consideration that in the AndroidManifest.xml i implemented this code

Comment: <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" /> Is this the problem???

Comment: @Ali Can you update your question with the full code you have in `notificationOpened`? You should have a `startActivity` line if you disable the default behavior of opening the launcher Activity.

Comment: OneSignal.startInit(this)         .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())         .init(); private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {     @Override     public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {             if (additionalData != null && additionalData.has("targetUrl"))                mWebView.loadUrl(additionalData.optString("targetUrl"));          }

Comment: @Ali Just updated my answer. In your case it would be simpler to call OneSignal init from your `Activity` class instead of `Application` as this way you won't need extra code manage the `Activity`. You will then need to remove the `com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT` entry.

Comment: you mean that i should remove meta data com.onesignal.notificationopened.default disable and everything will work correctly?????

Comment: @Ali Yes, as long as you have the webview on your launcher Activity and with the code above.

Comment: Exellent it works well and everything is ok Thank you jkasten you helped me alot                                                                                                Best Regards

Comment: I have enable logging and i have tested alot of things and i found the where the problem is exactly
The exact problem is if the app is opened and a notification received it will automatically open the Link that is send using additional data while if the app is closed and a notification received when i tap on the notification it open the main activity in other words it open the main webview page and not the Link that its sent with the additional data

This is the exact problem that i am facing 

Is their any solution???

Regards